# Is this the correct way to configure "Global settings" in WCF Serviced, Delivered through IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service written.  I want it to pick up some "global settings" upon startup.  The WCF service will run under IIS.

Here's how I am doing it, but I want to make sure this is the correct way.  Can an expert comment?

1. I put the relevant data in web.config.  Now I don't believe I can access this in my WCF class as such, so...
2. I've created a Global.asax file, and in its `Application_Start` method, I read in the relevant data into an object, which I place into the `AppDomain` using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("MySettings", settingsObj);`
3. Then in my WCF Service Implementation class I have a static constructor.  This reads the relevant global object from the `AppDomain` using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("MySettings");`

This all seems to work, but I'm wondering if this is the correct way?  I understand why the WCF service implementation has no access to the `HttpContext`.

Thanks,
Dermot.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother using GetData and SetData methods. When I need the values I would just pull them from the config file with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["your_key"]`, or inject them into the service instance constructor by implementing a custom [IInstanceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx).

Comment: My Settings object is something I read in from an XML file in Application_Start.  It is a complex object, not just a string, So I don't believe I can put it into AppSettings